# How can I fix "Unable to activate constraint ~~ " error?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit, stackview

I'm trying to make ui using snapkit and practice MVVM pattern, but when I try to add stackview I keep getting an error that says

> 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001753fc0 "UIStackView:0x10380aba0.centerY"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001753a00 "UIImageView:0x103905b00.centerY"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

When I comment out the stackview code line, everything works well, so I guess there is something wrong with the stackview.

This is Post.swift code.

```swift
struct Post {
    let userHandle: String
    let userProfileImage: String
    let location: String
    let selfieImage: String
    let rearViewImage: String
    let caption: String
    
    init(userHandle: String, userProfileImage: String, location: String, selfieImage: String, rearViewImage: String, caption: String) {
        self.userHandle = userHandle
        self.userProfileImage = userProfileImage
        self.location = location
        self.selfieImage = selfieImage
        self.rearViewImage = rearViewImage
        self.caption = caption
    }
}
```

This is PostView.swift code.

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class PostView: UIView {
    var userProfileImageName: String = "" {
        willSet {
            userProfileImageView.image = UIImage(named: newValue)
            print("userProfileImage: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    
    var selfieImageName: String = "" {
        willSet {
            selfieImageView.image = UIImage(named: newValue)
            print("selfieImage: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    
    var rearImageName: String = "" {
        willSet {
            rearViewImageView.image = UIImage(named: newValue)
            print("rearImage: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    
    let userProfileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
    lazy var userHandleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .natural
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .semibold)
        label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var locationLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.textColor = .lightGray
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    
    var stackView: UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5
        return stackView
    }
    
    let selfieImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        return imageView
    }()
    
    let rearViewImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        return imageView
    }()
    
    let captionLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .semibold)
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(userHandleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(locationLabel)
        
        addSubview(rearViewImageView)
        addSubview(captionLabel)
        
        // constraint
        userProfileImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
            make.width.equalTo(50)
            make.height.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.width)
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.centerY)
make.leading.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
                
        rearViewImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make inmake.top.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            // height == width * 4/3
make.height.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.width).multipliedBy(4.0 / 3.0)
            // don't need this
            //make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
                
        captionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.bottom).offset(5)
            make.leading.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.leading)
            make.trailing.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.trailing)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

This is PostViewModel.swift code.

```swift
class PostViewModel {
    private let post: Post
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
    }
    
    var userHandle: String {
        return post.userHandle
    }
    
    var userProfileImage: String {
        return post.userProfileImage
    }
    
    var location: String {
        return post.location
    }
    
    var selfieImage: String{
        return post.selfieImage
    }
    
    var rearViewImage: String {
        return post.rearViewImage
    }
    
    var caption: String {
        return post.caption
    }
}

extension PostViewModel {
    func configure(_ view: PostView){
        view.locationLabel.text = location
        view.captionLabel.text = caption
        view.rearImageName = rearViewImage
        view.selfieImageName = selfieImage
        view.userProfileImageName = userProfileImage
        
        view.userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        print("== \(view.userProfileImageView.layer.cornerRadius)")
    }
}
```

This is the viewcontroller.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let newPost = Post(userHandle: "userHandle", userProfileImage: "profileImage.png", location: "A location", selfieImage: "selfieImage.jpg", rearViewImage: "rearImage.jpg", caption: "BeReal")
        //let postView = PostView()
        let postViewModel = PostViewModel(post: newPost)
        let postView = PostView()
        postViewModel.configure(postView)

        view.addSubview(postView)

        postView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            //make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }

        postView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
}
```

I also tried making the stackview's constraint with equalToSuperview(), but I get `Fatal error: Expected superview but found nil when attempting make constraint` equalToSuperview`.`  error, so I guess stackview is not being added...?
I also double-checked that I'm adding subview before making constraints. I just can't figure out what causes this error.

Comment: 1. Don't use the same view when setting constraint to the same view, in your case "userProfileImageView" and "rearViewImageView"

2. remove this line "make.width.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.height).multipliedBy(1.0)" and set a height constraint for that view(userProfileImageView)

3. stackView is not having height and width constraint

Answer (score 0):

You must have left out some code ... because I don't get the `no common ancestor` error you're getting.

However, we can make a couple changes to "clean up" your constraints... see the inline comments in this modification to your code.

A tip: when initially working on your layout, give the UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see the framing.

---

**UIView subclass**:

```
class UserView: UIView {
    
    let userProfileImageView = UIImageView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let userHandleLabel = UILabel()
    let locationLabel = UILabel()
    let rearViewImageView = UIImageView()
    let captionLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        // let's use some contrasting background colors so we can see the framing
        userProfileImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        rearViewImageView.backgroundColor = .blue

        userHandleLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        locationLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        captionLabel.backgroundColor = .green

        // let's set images for the image views
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person") {
            userProfileImageView.image = img
            userProfileImageView.tintColor = .lightGray
        }
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "r.square") {
            rearViewImageView.image = img
            rearViewImageView.tintColor = .lightGray
        }

        // some text in the labels so we can see them
        userHandleLabel.text = "userHandleLabel"
        locationLabel.text = "locationLabel"
        captionLabel.text = "captionLabel"
        
        // now let's add the UI elements to the view hierarchy
        addSubview(userProfileImageView)
        addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(userHandleLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(locationLabel)
        
        addSubview(rearViewImageView)
        addSubview(captionLabel)
        
        // constraints
        
        userProfileImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            // inset 5-points from top and leading of self
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
            // width == 50
            make.width.equalTo(50)
            // height == width
            make.height.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.width)
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            // leading 5-points from profile image view trailing
            make.centerY.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.centerY)
            // centered vertically to profile image view
            make.leading.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.trailing).offset(5)
        }
        
        rearViewImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            // top 10-points from profile image view bottom
            make.top.equalTo(userProfileImageView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            // "full width"
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            // height == width * 4/3
            make.height.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.width).multipliedBy(4.0 / 3.0)
            // don't need this
            //make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        captionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            // top 5-points from rear view image view bottom
            make.top.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.bottom).offset(5)
            // leading == rear view image view leading
            make.leading.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.leading)
            //  *probably* also want to constrain the trailing
            make.trailing.equalTo(rearViewImageView.snp.trailing)
            // bottom 10-points from bottom of self
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10)

            // note: the bottom constraint also sets the Height of self,
            //  provided we don't constrain it differently "from outside"
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

---

**Simple test view controller**

```
class TestUserViewVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = UserView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(testView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        testView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            // top, leading, trailing 20-points inset from safe-area
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(g).inset(20.0)
            // we don't give it a Height constraint, because
            //  UserView's internal constraints will set the height
        }
    }
    
}
```

---

Result:

[image]

You didn't show setting any stack view properties, but I'm guessing you want the two labels to be vertical with a little "gap":

```
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.spacing = 4
```

gives us this:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *after OP updated original code...*

In the code you left our of your original post, you have this in your `PostView` class:

```
var stackView: UIStackView {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 5
    return stackView
}
```

You're missing the `=` on the first line, and the `()` on the last line:

```
var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 5
    return stackView
}()
```

So, you've created a function that returns a `UIStackView`, as opposed to actually creating a `UIStackView`

Comment: thank you for the comment!! But I still get the same error.. :( Now what I'm thinking is that there is something going on with the MVVM pattern in my project. Because actually, what I'm doing is to practice MVVM pattern + making layout programmatically... I'll upload the whole code of the project, and can you go through it and see if something is not right, please? I'm new to MVVM and making UI programmatically :(

Comment: @suyeon - see the **Edit** at the end of my answer.

Comment: my god.. cannot believe I left that out  thank you so much!